# How to show map view with mark and get the longitude and latitude to textview

Tags: java, android, google-maps, mapview

**in my android application, i have to get user location , by user locating the marker in mapview, then textview below to map view will display the longitude and latitude, how to do it**

Answer (score 0):

in my code i use this code for take value latitude and longitude

```
 LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
```

after this you can create Marker on map

```
place_on_map = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng);
```